# Query returning data outside the scope of the WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to retrieve summarized data from the table depending on DateTime and state.
The problem is I need multiple state values ex. 'where 1 or 2 or 3'

```
SELECT SUM(ticketTotalAmount)
FROM tickets 
WHERE ticketDate >= '2019/04/01 00:00:00' AND ticketDate <= '2019/04/02 23:59:59'
  AND ticketState = 'STAND BY'
   OR ticketState = 'WIN'
   OR ticketState = 'LOSE'
```

The output should retrieve summarized data based on any of those 3 states, Win, Lose or Standby and in the range of the ticketDate but the actual output is beyond the scope of DateTime restrictions.

Removing the state conditions and leaving only the DateTime retrieves data within the scope of the condition. The problem is there are more than these 3 states.

Comment: Mixing AND with OR requires some care...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the order of the `AND` and `OR` clauses.

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(ticketTotalAmount)
FROM   tickets 
WHERE  ticketDate >= '2019/04/01 00:00:00' AND ticketDate <= '2019/04/02 23:59:59' AND
       (ticketState = 'STAND BY' OR ticketState = 'WIN' OR ticketState = 'LOSE');
```

Or even better:

```
SELECT SUM(ticketTotalAmount)
FROM   tickets 
WHERE  ticketDate BETWEEN '2019/04/01 00:00:00' AND '2019/04/02 23:59:59'
  AND  ticketState IN ('STAND BY', 'WIN', 'LOSE');
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the ticket state conditions within round brackets

```
SELECT SUM(ticketTotalAmount) FROM tickets 
WHERE ticketDate >= '2019/04/01 00:00:00' AND ticketDate <= '2019/04/02 23:59:59' AND ( ticketState = 'STAND BY' OR ticketState = 'WIN' OR ticketState = 'LOSE')
```

Answer (score 1):

use `IN`

```
SELECT SUM(ticketTotalAmount) FROM tickets 
WHERE ticketDate >= '2019/04/01 00:00:00' AND ticketDate <= '2019/04/02 23:59:59' 
AND ticketState in( 'STAND BY' , 'WIN' ,'LOSE')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend writing the query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(t.ticketTotalAmount)
FROM tickets t
WHERE t.ticketDate >= '2019-04-01' AND
      t.ticketDate < '2019-04-03' AND
      t.ticketState IN ('STAND BY', 'WIN', 'LOSE');
```

Note the changes to the query:

- Instead of `OR`, use `IN`.  It is clearer.  This fixes your explicit problem.
- The date logic is simplified, so you don't have to deal with time values (or with values that occur during the last few milliseconds of the day).
- The table aliases are a good idea; I generally consider them optional on queries with only one table.

Answer (score 1):

Using `IN([...])` is easier to read, but it's useful to see and understand the use of parens to group criteria, so that you get the results you're looking for. Example:

```
SELECT SUM(ticketTotalAmount)
FROM tickets 
WHERE
        ticketDate >= '2019/04/01 00:00:00'
    AND ticketDate <= '2019/04/02 23:59:59'
    AND 
    (
           ticketState = 'STAND BY'
        OR ticketState = 'WIN'
        OR ticketState = 'LOSE'
    )
```